# Session variables don't update on every page

Tags: php, session, session-variables

On my website, there is a function for logging in and logging out. Upon login, I set the session variables *pass* (which is hashed password), *uid* which is the ID of the user logged in and *loggedIn* (boolean):

```
    $hashedpass = **hashed pass**;
    $_SESSION['pass'] = $hashedpass or die("Fel 2");
    $_SESSION['uid'] = $uid or die("Fel 3");
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true or die("Fel 4");
    header("Location:indexloggedin.php");
```

On every page, I check if the visitor is logged in by

1. Checking the status of `$_SESSION['loggedIn']`,
2. Searching the database for the user with the ID `$_SESSION['uid']`,
3. Checking if the hashed password in the database matches the hashed password in the session variable:

   ```
   $sespass = $_SESSION['pass'];
   $sesid = $_SESSION['uid'];

   $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '$sesid'";

   $result2 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql2);
   $numrows2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
   if ($numrows2 != 1) {
       $userOk = false;
   }
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
       $dbpass = $row['pass'];
   }

   if ($sespass != $dbpass) {
       $userOk = false;
   } else {
       $userOk = true;
   }
   ```

My problem is that this seems to be working on some pages, while it doesn't work at others. For example, when I log in, I am instantly logged in to the homepage, but not to the profile page. However, after a few reloads, I am logged in to the profile page as well. The same thing happens when logging out.

For testing purposes, I tried to var_dump the password variables as well as the userOk status on the index page, and this is where I noticed something interesting. When I log out, the password variables are set to be empty, and `$userOk` is `false`, according to what that is shown at `index.php?msg=loggedout`. But when I remove the `?msg=loggedout` (and only leave `index.php`), the password variables are back to their previous value, and I am no longer logged out... After a few reloads, I am once again logged out.

Why is my session variables not working as expected? It feels like as if it takes time for them to update, which is very weird. I have tried with caching disabled (both through headers and through the Cache setting in my browser).

Just tell me if you need more info.

Comment: There are some issues with your code only... share us the whole pages

Comment: It's good practise to always use trim( ) before inserting the id or session into db

Comment: where's `session_start()`?

Comment: It is in those files, just not in what I posted here. @CodeGodie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting my hosting provider, it was actually a hosting issue. It is now resolved!

Thanks,
Jacob

Answer (score 0):

You have initialization `session_start()` on every Site?

`session_start()` creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

Comment: I understand you cant yet write comments but this is too short to be an answer. Rewrite your answer with more details and explain why `session_start` is needed.

Comment: Yes, I am using session_start() on every page.